# IE confused about triggering div onclick event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, triggers, dom-events

I have the block of code below on top of Page1,2,3,4,5 to navigate through 5 pages.
Everything works fine in Chrome and Mozilla. But in IE it always redirects to Page5 when I want to navigate to a bigger number page.

"selected" class is attached only on related page div. The divs after "selected" class is not working properly in IE.

```
<div class='tabmenu'>
<div onclick="document.location='Page1.php'">Page1</div>
<div onclick="document.location='Page2.php'">Page2</div>
<div class="selected" onclick="document.location='Page3.php'">Page3</div>
<div onclick="document.location='Page4.php'">Page4</div>
<div onclick="document.location='Page5.php'">Page5</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.tabmenu {text-align: left; margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px;font: bold 12px sans-serif;border-bottom: 1px solid #ff6600;padding: 3px;}
.tabmenu div {display: inline;padding: 3px 5px;border: 1px solid #000;background-color: #ddddff;color: #333;margin-left: 5px;border-bottom: none;cursor: pointer;}
.tabmenu .selected {border:1px solid #ff6600;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;background-color: #fff;color: #ff6600;position: relative;}
```

Examples:

- Clicking Page2 when on Page1 -> Navigates to Page5 (only in IE).
- Clicking Page4 when on Page1 -> Navigates to Page5 (only in IE).
- Clicking Page5 when on Page3 -> Navigates to Page5 (only in IE).
- Clicking Page1 when on Page2 -> Navigates to Page1 (works fine).
- Clicking Page2 when on Page3 -> Navigates to Page2 (works fine).
- Clicking Page3 when on Page5 -> Navigates to Page3 (works fine).

I am very stuck on this. Any ideas why this fails?

Comment: What's wrong with the `<a>` tag? Why the `onclick` everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran it in IE 8 and it works fine.  What version of IE are you using?  Also, make srue you have Javascript enabled in IE.

Comment: I edited my first post. I just found out it has something to do with the "selected" class. the divs after that class is not working properly in ie.